# Why does FParsec use lists?

Tags: fparsec

I thought I'd try writing a fast parser using FParsec and quickly realised that `many` returning a list is a seriously performance problem. Then I discovered an alternative that uses a `ResizeArray` in the docs:

```
let manyA2 p1 p =
    Inline.Many(firstElementParser = p1,
                elementParser = p,
                stateFromFirstElement = (fun x0 ->
                                             let ra = ResizeArray<_>()
                                             ra.Add(x0)
                                             ra),
                foldState = (fun ra x -> ra.Add(x); ra),
                resultFromState = (fun ra -> ra.ToArray()),
                resultForEmptySequence = (fun () -> [||]))

let manyA p = manyA2 p p
```

Using this in my code instead makes it run several times faster. So why does FParsec use lists by default instead of `ResizeArray`?

Comment: Unless a member of the team contributes this will be speculation at best... and thus possibly not a good fit for stackoverflow. From personal experience with writing similar things, focusing on getting things working in a maintainable fashion over performance tends to be a more profitable strategy... at least for the first few version of a product. As long as something is working "fast enough" then everyone is happy.

Comment: I agree but the author has replied. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the built-in F# list type as the result type for the sequence combinators  makes the combinators more convenient to use in F# and arguably leads to more idiomatic client-side code. Since most F# developers value simplicity and elegance over performance (at least in my experience) using lists as the default seemed like the right choice when I designed the API. At the same time I tried to make it easy for users to define their own specialized sequence combinators.

Currently the sequence combinators that return a list also use a list internally for building up the sequence. This is suboptimal for sequences with more than about 2 elements, as the list has to be reversed before it is returned. However, I'm not sure whether changing the implementation would be worth the effort, since if your parser is performance sensitive and you're parsing long sequence you're better off not using lists at all.

I probably should add a section about using arrays instead of lists to the user's guide chapter on performance.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Now that I think of it I am not sure what a better alternative would be. A `ResizeArray` would be great inside one `many` but if you have `many (many ...)` then you would want something you can concatenate efficiently.

Comment: For a performance critical parser (combinator) function, you always have the option to drop down to FParsec's low-level API and implement the parser "manually". For a nested sequence combinator this would e.g. allow you to parse the elements into a single container. It would also allow you to skip the delimiters and whitespace using direct `CharStream` method calls, which might give you a nice little additional performance boost.